# How to delete a discussion from SharePoint Online - Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, delete

I have full admin rights to our SharePoint/Office 365 and I've added several test discussions in a discussion board.  When I open a discussion, I don't see any delete options on the List ribbon or anywhere else!

Any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

I found it by clicking on the discussion, then at the bottom of the original discussion post, Reply/Edit/... - click on "..." Delete appears.

Comment: does not appear that you can delete from Outlook 2016; that this online delete is the only delete there is

Answer (score 0):

There is an "X" that appears to the right of the discussion - click to delete?